# Como gravar resultado do SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

Eu preciso inserir dados em uma tabela A, mas tenho um dado desconhecido e preciso busca-lo na tabela B.

Assim, preciso fazer um SELECT na tabela B e salva-lo para posterior inserção na tabela A.

Eu consegui o resultado esperado, mas é uma solução paliativa:

```
$cod = $_POST['descricao']; 
$produto = $_POST['codigoproduto'];
$quant = $_POST['quantidade'];

$sqlcode = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabelaA(codigo, codigoproduto, quantidade) SELECT codigo, 9212, codigo FROM tabelaB WHERE descricao='$cod'");
$sqlcode1 = mysql_query("UPDATE tabelaA SET codigoproduto='$produto', quantidade='$quant' WHERE codigoproduto=9212");
```

Como fazer corretamente?

Comment: O problema está sendo pegar o retorno da query?

Comment: Qual campo você precisa pegar da tabelaB? É o campo `codigo`?

Comment: @Oeslei exato o campo `codigo`

Comment: que tal `$sqlcode = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabelaA(codigo, codigoproduto, quantidade) SELECT codigo, '$produto', '$quant' FROM tabelaB WHERE descricao='$cod'");`?

Comment: @Bacco Eu preciso saber o valor do campo `codigo`, na tabelaB `WHERE descricao='$cod'` para depois utilizar o valor do `codigo` na tabelaA. Deu pra entender? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você já notou ao usar a constante `9212` no `INSERT..SELECT`, você pode fixar alguns dos valores retornados pelo SELECT - digo, em vez de obter o valor da tabela, você define uma constante para representar o valor do campo.

Assim, no seu comando INSERT, você pode obter um valor da tabela e os demais valores você obtém das suas variáveis:

```
$sqlcode = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabelaA(codigo, codigoproduto, quantidade) SELECT codigo, '$produto', '$quant' FROM tabelaB WHERE descricao='$cod'");
```

Lembrando apenas, como de costume, que você está confiando em informações do usuário e mandando elas direto para o seu banco de dados, o que é uma falha de segurança (ver "SQL Injection").

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. O que você quer dizer com "informações do usuário"? No meu caso, todas essas variáveis são provenientes de uma aplicação, ou seja, o usuário só informa a quantidade

Comment: @ReneSá Sempre que você concatena na sua query um valor que foi obtido de fora do seu aplicativo (que venha de outro aplicativo, ou de um arquivo de configuração, ou que tenha sido entrado pelo usuário) você está sujeito a SQL Injection. Se a "quantidade" informada pelo usuário é esta que você concatena na sua query, você está sujeito a SQL Injection. Se livrar deste risco e ainda possivelmente ganhar performance é simples: dê uma olhada em como usar parâmetros em comandos SQL em vez de concatená-los na query. Sucesso aí!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar uma `subquery`, que é uma `query` dentro da outra, desta forma:

```
$cod = $_POST['descricao']; 
$produto = $_POST['codigoproduto'];
$quant = $_POST['quantidade'];

// aconselho a usar o LIMIT 1 para agilizar a consulta
$selectCodigo = "SELECT codigo FROM tabelaB WHERE descricao LIKE $cod LIMIT 1";

// não esqueça dos parênteses entre a variável $selectCodigo
// os parênteses são necessários para separar a subquery da query principal
$sqlcode = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabelaA (codigo, codigoproduto, quantidade) VALUES (($selectCodigo), $produto, $quant)");
```